# Restful API Response: Nesting Objects vs Adding new fields

Tags: java, json, api, rest

Let's say we have a `ProductType` table in our database. This represents the types of products that can exist:

| productTypeId | name | description | capacity | pricePerNight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tent | This is a tent | 4 | 20 |

Let's say we have a `Product` table in our database. This represents actual physical `Products` that exist (i.e. in a rental shop's inventory):

| id | productTypeId (FK) | condition | lastUsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | good | 18/11/21 |
| 7 | 1 | bad | 18/11/21 |
| 8 | 1 | medium | 18/11/21 |

Now, let's say I was making a public API which allows clients to query all available products and the price of those products for a specific set of dates.

My options are: (a) Return an edited version of the `ProductType` object with new fields (e.g. `quantityAvailable` and `priceForDates`) conveying the extra information requested:

```
{
        "productTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Tent",
        "description": "This is a tent",
        "capacity": 4,
        "quantityAvailable": 1,
        "priceForDates": 60,
}
```

(b) Wrap the `ProductType` object in a parent object then add extra fields (e.g. `quantityAvailable` and `priceForDates`) to the parent object:

```
{
         "quantityAvailable": 3,
         "priceForDates": 60,
         "product":
                   {
                      "productTypeId": 1,
                      "name": "Tent",
                      "description": "This is a tent",
                      "capacity": 4,
                   }

}
```

I am confronted by this situation quite regularly and I'm wondering what is the best practice for a RESTful API.

IRL I am building a public API which needs to be as intuitive and easy to use as possible for our company's integrating partners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is borderline opinion-based but still, this is my take on this.

I would go with option (b). The reason is that you might be exposing your `ProductType` as the following in other endpoints:

```java
"product": {
   "productTypeId": 1,
   "name": "Tent",
   "description": "This is a tent",
   "capacity": 4,
}
```

In this case, it is important to be consistent and to represent `ProductType` with the same structure in all your endpoints.

On top of this, this seems the response to the call of checking the availability of a product for a given period of days. Even the way you phrased it "*(...) allows clients to query all available products and the price of those products for a specific set of dates.*" shows that the price and the number of available products are just additional information about a given `ProductType`. Hence, they should be included alongside `ProductType` but not as part of `ProductType`. For example `priceForDates` is clearly not a `ProductType` property.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would agree, it's important to maintain the consistency/integrity of data across endpoints. But (a) is more convenient imo, (e.g. when client is iterating through a list). What about going with (a) and including the quantityAvailable and priceForDates in all endpoints. quantityAvailable and priceForDates could be set to null when they aren't used or relevant. Or is this bad practice?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Not only I don't think it is easier for any client (iterating a list of (a) or (b) is equally simple, and (b) is better organized) but you must not add attributes to other endpoints that are not relevant in those cases just because you need them elsewhere. Option (b) is by far the best option.